# Split and add new string between string to rename the path in sftp

Tags: linux, shell

I have a file which contains paths. I want to loop over the file and change the path.
I want to change path from `/dir/file1.txt` to /`dir/temp/file1.txt`

```
while read p; do
  # update the string from /dir/filename.txt to /dir/temp/filename.txt
done < file_list.txt
```

UPDATE:
I have created this, don't know why it is failing

```
while read p; do
  arr=(${p//// })
  dest="/${arr[0]}/temp/${arr[1]}"
  rename $p $dest | SFTP -i private_key username@host
done < file_list.txt
```

> error rename: not enough arguments

Answer (score 0):

I know it is not a most effective way, but for now it is working fine.

```
while read p; do
  arr=(${p//// })
  dest="/${arr[0]}/temp/${arr[1]}"
  SFTP -i private_key username@host <<< "rename $p $dest"
done < file_list.txt
```